# TcpListener and TcpClient connection fails when changing from localhost to actual IP address

Tags: c#, networking

I'm attempting to create a simple piece of software to 'chat' between two computers to test out Networking. At the moment, all I have done is copied the TcpListener (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcplistener?view=netframework-4.8) and TcpClient (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.sockets.tcpclient?view=netframework-4.8) code to see how it works (code at end).

It all works great, but once I replace localhost ("127.0.0.1") in both files with my actual IP address (my IPv4 address that I got by typing 'ipconfig' into the command console on windows), the two won't connect.

Are there some settings I need to configure? Is this a firewall issue or something?  Or am i just being super dumb? I am pretty new to C# networking.

Thanks for any help!

TcpListener:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Text;

class MyTcpListener
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        TcpListener server=null;   
        try
        {
            // Set the TcpListener on port 13000.
            Int32 port = 13000;
            IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("127.0.0.1");

            // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
            server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);

            // Start listening for client requests.
            server.Start();

            // Buffer for reading data
            Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
            String data = null;

            // Enter the listening loop.
            while(true) 
            {
                Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();            
                Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                data = null;

                // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                int i;

                // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                while((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length))!=0) 
                {   
                    // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                    data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                    Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                    // Process the data sent by the client.
                    data = data.ToUpper();

                    byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                    // Send back a response.
                    stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                    Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);            
                }

                // Shutdown and end connection
                client.Close();
            }
        }
        catch(SocketException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
        }
        finally
        {
            // Stop listening for new clients.
            server.Stop();
        }

        Console.WriteLine("\nHit enter to continue...");
        Console.Read();
      }   
}
```

TcpClient:

```
using System;
using System.Net.Sockets;

namespace Client
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Connect("127.0.0.1", "Test");
        }

        static void Connect(String server, String message) 
        {
            try 
            {
                // Create a TcpClient.
                // Note, for this client to work you need to have a TcpServer 
                // connected to the same address as specified by the server, port
                // combination.
                Int32 port = 13000;
                TcpClient client = new TcpClient(server, port);

                // Translate the passed message into ASCII and store it as a Byte array.
                Byte[] data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(message);         

                // Get a client stream for reading and writing.
               //  Stream stream = client.GetStream();

                NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                // Send the message to the connected TcpServer. 
                stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);

                Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", message);         

                // Receive the TcpServer.response.

                // Buffer to store the response bytes.
                data = new Byte[256];

                // String to store the response ASCII representation.
                String responseData = String.Empty;

                // Read the first batch of the TcpServer response bytes.
                Int32 bytes = stream.Read(data, 0, data.Length);
                responseData = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, bytes);
                Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", responseData);         

                // Close everything.
                stream.Close();         
                client.Close();         
            } 
            catch (ArgumentNullException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("ArgumentNullException: {0}", e);
            } 
            catch (SocketException e) 
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }

            Console.WriteLine("\n Press Enter to continue...");
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:
I DO get an exception, sorry:

```
SocketException: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IPv4]:13000
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.DoConnect(EndPoint endPointSnapshot, SocketAddress socketAddress)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(EndPoint remoteEP)
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Connect(IPAddress address, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient.Connect(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at System.Net.Sockets.TcpClient..ctor(String hostname, Int32 port)
   at Client.Client.Connect(String server, String message) in C:\Users\[User]\Documents\[User]\Programming\GenericC#\Client\Client.cs:line 22
```

Comment: What error you're getting when trying to connect with your actual IP?

Comment: Please, provide your code. We cannot help you without it. Plus, what address did you paste? Your LAN Ip?

Comment: Your code works fine for me. Make sure when you take the IP address from the `ipconfig` output, you use your actual LAN IP address. Often the command will display multiple adapters, such as a wifi adapter plus a VM adapter. You want your actual LAN address (e.g. a hard-wired Ethernet or wifi adapter). You of course also need to double-check that you did in fact update _both_ programs to use the same IP address. All that said, for the server it's usually better to use `IPAddress.Any` and receive connections on any adapter.

Comment: @PeterDuniho Which IP address do I use - when I use ipconfig it gives me one IPv4, but when I look up "What is my IP address" and different one comes up. At the moment, I'm using the latter but it says 'No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it' - is this a firewall thing? Thanks for all the help so far.

Comment: For now, use the IP address that ipconfig shows you. The other one is your Internet-facing address. If you are at home, that's probably a NAT router of some sort (either built into your ISP's modem, or a separate component). If at work, it's something similar, but could be a more sophisticated proxy or something. In any case, that address won't work unless you have configured the router to forward traffic on your port to the server's LAN IP address. You might as well just use the server's LAN IP address from the outset for now (the ipconfig one), skip the middle-man and the config headaches :)

Comment: @PeterDuniho Ok thanks, but when I use the ipconfig one I get this error: SocketException: System.Net.Internals.SocketExceptionFactory+ExtendedSocketException (10060): A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond. [IPv4]:13000. If I put my IPv6 it ways it is actively refused again.

Answer (score -2):

easy enough to test and see if it is a firewall issue.

1. Open a command prompt
2. Type command telnet " " so you'd do on the machine stating the connection.If no error you're having a clear path and your application accepted the connection.
3. Have a look at the [Firewall logs](https://www.howtogeek.com/220204/how-to-track-firewall-activity-with-the-windows-firewall-log/) to see if a issue was
   generated.

If possible you should allow your application to communicate in and out (if both are needed)

if you need to you could open the ports with your code (need elevated permission) if you see that the rule is missing. StackOverfow has quite a few example for this

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Will this work on just one device? At the moment the client and server are running on the same device - will this still work?

Comment: Yes, you should not use the loopback IP address but your normal IP Address as the LoopBack Normally is not affected by a firewall